# using DateTime.Ticks instead of DateTime itself, Is this a good practice?

Tags: .net, performance, design-patterns, database-design, design-principles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I store DateTimes as a Long (Ticks) in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195621/should-i-store-datetimes-as-a-long-ticks-in-a-database)

It is OK to use `DateTime.Ticks` instead of `DateTime` itself for implementing `DateTime` based operations? For example changing type of database column from `DATETIME` into `BIGINT` and then storing `123456789123456` value into it in instead of `2012-06-02 14:26:08.727`?

I know in this case we've to handle conversions, but there is several pros. for example there is no limit in date-time range for storing and also we wouldn't worry about database supported types {date, datetime, smalldate} etc.

Actually I want to ensure about this approach in two field:

1. Design Principles
2. Performance issues

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have voted to close as exact duplicate, but I want to give my two cents on this.
It seems like a mythical [Columbus Egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_of_Columbus), but you are looking for too much trouble for the benefit gained.

Every single access to your database that involves dates should be converted to (easy,fast) and from (not cheap) dates. But, worst of all, if, for whatever reason, you need to do maintenance work on this 'ticks' fields (without the use of your own program) you are out in the cold because you need to do all manually (conversion I mean).